# react-native-maps fitToSuppliedMarker/fitToCorodinates does not show all markers

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-maps

i am trying to use simple MapView and display 2 markers.

they both appear correctly on map view but not visible on screen at same time (Image1 rendered by default)

i have to perform manual drag operation before  both markers can be seen on screen.(Image2 after i manually drag map so that they can be seen on screen)

i tried using fitToSuppliedMarkers/fitToCocordinates but nothing seems to work.

```
export default class FavItemMapView extends Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
        position:{
            latitude:1.286353,
            longitude:103.853067,
            latitudeDelta: 0,
            longitudeDelta: 0,
        },
        error:null
    }
    this.mapRef = null;
}

componentWillMount(){

    const favPlaceLatitude = parseFloat(this.props.navigation.state.params.latitude)
    const favPlaceLongitude = parseFloat(this.props.navigation.state.params.longitude)
    markers.push({latitude:favPlaceLatitude,longitude:favPlaceLongitude});
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        (position) => {
          console.log("wokeeey" + width + height);
          console.log(position);
          var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude)
          var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude)

          var initialRegion = {
            latitude: lat,
            longitude: long,
            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
          }

          this.onRegionChange(initialRegion)
        },
        (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
        { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 },
      );
}

onRegionChange(region) {
    this.setState({ position:region })
}

componentDidMount(){
    //this.mapRef.fitToSuppliedMarkers(markerIDs,true);
    const favPlaceLatitude = parseFloat(this.props.navigation.state.params.latitude)
    const favPlaceLongitude = parseFloat(this.props.navigation.state.params.longitude)
    this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates([{latitude:favPlaceLatitude,longitude:favPlaceLongitude}], {
        edgePadding: {
          bottom: 200, right: 50, top: 150, left: 50,
        },
        animated: true,
    });
}

render(){

    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const favPlaceLatitude = parseFloat(navigation.state.params.latitude)
    const favPlaceLongitude = parseFloat(navigation.state.params.longitude)

    return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MapView provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE} ref={ref => {this.mapRef = ref;}} style={styles.map} region={this.state.position}>
                {this.state.position.latitude &&
                    <MapView.Marker identifier="Marker2" coordinate={{latitude:this.state.position.latitude,longitude:this.state.position.longitude}} pinColor="red"/>
                }
                {this.state.position.longitude &&
                    <MapView.Marker identifier="Marker1" coordinate={{latitude:favPlaceLatitude,longitude:favPlaceLongitude}} pinColor="green"/>
                }
            </MapView>
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles={
  container:{
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  map:{
    padding:100,
    ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject
  }
}
```

can you someone suggest what is wrong? attaching simulator image for reference.
[image]
[image]

Comment: did u find any solution ?

Comment: @AhmedImam did you figured this out?

Answer (score 10):

```
<MapView
    provider={MapView.PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    ref={map => {this.map = map}}
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    initialRegion={{latitude:this.state.request.latitude,
      longitude:this.state.request.longitude,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,}}
    onMapReady={() => {this.map.fitToSuppliedMarkers(['mk1','mk2'],{ edgePadding: 
      {top: 50,
        right: 50,
        bottom: 50,
        left: 50}

    })}}
    >
    <Marker
    image={require('../../../assets/pin.png')}
    coordinate={{latitude:this.state.request.latitude,longitude:this.state.request.longitude}} 
    title='Punto de partida'
    identifier={'mk1'}
    >

    </Marker>

    <Marker
    image={require('../../../assets/pin_final.png')}
    coordinate={{latitude:this.state.request.latitude_destinity,longitude:this.state.request.longitude_destinity}} 
    title='Punto de destino'
    identifier={'mk2'}
>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. I used the `identifier` tags for each `Marker` to get a reference to each one as a string in the `fitToSuppliedMarkers` method.

Answer (score 3):

So from my experience with working with this library - I found out the best experience is to utilize the `onMapReady` prop on the MapView component.

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#events

```
<MapView
  ...
  onMapReady{() => {
    this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(...)
  }}
/>
```

OR

```
<MapView
  ...
  onMapReady{() => {
    this.mapRef.fitToSuppliedMarkers(...)
  }}
/>
```

Let me know if that helped or not, I'm still learning it, but this approach is assuming you have the markers readily available that you are passing into your Map Component to render.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the best approach is to use `fitToElements` in iOS and `fitToSuppliedMarkers` (or `fitToCoordinates`) in Android. My resulting code end up something like this:

```js
import React, { useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, LatLng, Marker } from 'react-native-maps';

type Props = {
  origin: LatLng;
  destination: LatLng;
}

export default function ({ origin, destination }: Props) {
    const ref = useRef<MapView>(null);

    // effects
    const onMapReadyHandler = useCallback(() => {
      if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        ref?.current?.fitToElements(false);
      } else {
        ref?.current?.fitToCoordinates([origin, destination], {
          animated: true,
          edgePadding: {
            top: 150,
            right: 50,
            bottom: 50,
            left: 50,
          },
        });
      }
    }, [ref]);

    // UI
    return (
      <MapView
        style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
        ref={ref}
        provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
        onMapReady={onMapReadyHandler}
      >
        <Marker coordinate={origin} identifier="origin" />
        <Marker coordinate={destination} identifier="destination" />
      </MapView>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

That's how I center all my markers in react native :

```
const fitAllMarkers = () => {
map.current.fitToCoordinates(data, {
  edgePadding: {
    top: 20,
    right: 100,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 100,
  },
  animated: true,
});
};


  <MapView
    ref={map}
    provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: data[0]?.latitude ,
      longitude: data[0]?.longitude ,
      latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
      longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
    }}
    onMapReady={fitAllMarkers}
    onMapLoaded={fitAllMarkers}>
    {data?.map((item, ind) => {
      return (
        <Marker
          description={item.address}
          key={ind}
          identifier={`id${ind}`}
          title={item.title}
          coordinate={{
            latitude: item.latitude,
            longitude: item.longitude,
          }}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../../assets/icons/locationPin.png')}
            style={{
              width: wp(10),
              height: wp(10),
              resizeMode: 'contain',
            }}
          />
        </Marker>
      );
    })}
  </MapView>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think most easiest way to use fitToSuppliedMarkers for both the platform is to use with in useEffect Hook along with setInterval()

it Worked Smoothly in my case!

Check the the Example,

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || Destination == null) return;

    var i = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("i Before", i);

      mapRef?.current?.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 100,
          right: 100,
          left: 100,
          bottom: 100,
          aimated: true,
        },
      });
      clearInterval(i);
      console.log("i After clear interval", i);
    }, 50);
  }, [origin, Destination]);
```

Full Source Code!

```js
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import React, {
  useCallback,
  useEffect,
  useLayoutEffect,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
import MapView, { Marker } from "react-native-maps";
import tw from "twrnc";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import {
  selectDestination,
  selectOrigin,
} from "../reduxtoolkit/Slices/navSlice";
import MapViewDirections from "react-native-maps-directions";
import { GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY, API_URL } from "@env";

const Map = () => {
  const origin = useSelector(selectOrigin);
  const Destination = useSelector(selectDestination);

  // console.log("Origin:", origin);
  // console.log("Destination:", Destination);
  const mapRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || Destination == null) return;

    var i = setInterval(() => {
      console.log("i Before", i);

      mapRef?.current?.fitToSuppliedMarkers(["origin", "destination"], {
        edgePadding: {
          top: 100,
          right: 100,
          left: 100,
          bottom: 100,
          aimated: true,
        },
      });
      clearInterval(i);
      console.log("i After clear interval", i);
    }, 50);
  }, [origin, Destination]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapView
        ref={mapRef}
        style={tw`flex-1`}
        initialRegion={{
          latitude: origin?.Location?.lat,
          longitude: origin?.Location?.lng,
          latitudeDelta: 0.005,
          longitudeDelta: 0.005,
        }}
        mapType="mutedStandard"
      >
        {origin && Destination && (
          <MapViewDirections
            origin={origin?.Description}
            destination={Destination?.Description}
            apikey={GOOGLE_MAPS_APIKEY}
            strokeWidth={5}
            strokeColor={"black"}
          />
        )}
        {origin?.Location && (
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: origin?.Location?.lat,
              longitude: origin?.Location?.lng,
            }}
            title={"Origin"}
            description={origin.Description}
            identifier="origin"
          />
        )}
        {Destination?.Location && (
          <Marker
            coordinate={{
              latitude: Destination?.Location?.lat,
              longitude: Destination?.Location?.lng,
            }}
            title={"Destination"}
            description={Destination.Description}
            identifier="destination"
          />
        )}
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Map;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Thank You !
Check Full Project Code  [Here](https://github.com/kishan7785/Uber)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md#:%7E:text=If%20you%20need%20to%20use%20this%20in%20ComponentDidMount%2C%20make%20sure%20you%20put%20it%20in%20a%20timeout%20or%20it%20will%20cause%20performance%20problems.%20Note%20edgePadding%20is%20Google%20Maps%20only), for the methods `fitToSuppliedMarkers`:

> If you need to use this in ComponentDidMount, make sure you put it in a timeout or it will cause performance problems. Note edgePadding is Google Maps only

and `fitToCoordinates` :

> If called in ComponentDidMount in android, it will cause an exception. It is recommended to call it from the MapView onLayout event.

This is also causing these methods to not work correctly, as shown in the question.

You need to use a timer to call the method after a short time in order for it to work, like so:

```
<MapView
    onMapReady={() => {
        var i = setInterval(() => { 
            this.mapRef.fitToCoordinates(...);
            clearInterval(i);
        }, 512);
    }}
    ref={(ref) => {
        this.mapRef = ref;
    }}
    ... // rest of MapView props
/>
```